# How concatenate strings and display that formated string in linux bash script?

Tags: linux, string, bash

i write below script

```
#!/bin/bash

str1="apple"
str2="banana"
str3="NA"
str4="lumia"
str5="nokia"

let maxarg=5

checkindex()
{
   while [ $maxarg -gt 0 ]
   do
        str="${str$maxarg}" //here is problem
        echo -e $str
        if [ "${str}" == "NA" ]
        then
            break
        fi

     ((maxarg--))
   done     

   printf "Index is %d\n" $maxarg
}

checkindex
```

when exicuting it i got `str1,str2....Index is 0` output but what i want to print `apple,banana....Index is 3` means catch the index where `NA` string found. Using `str="${str$maxarg}"`i tried to redirect the output of `str1,str2....str5` in `str` because  i am not going to use any `switch case` or `if..else` for comparing each string.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to [indirect expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  Replacing the line

```
    str="${str$maxarg}" //here is problem
```

with

```
    tmp="str${maxarg}"   # This sets the variable tmp to str1 and so on
    str=${!tmp}          # This performs indirect expansion to retrieve
                         # the value of the variable name stored in tmp
```

should make it work.